# How can i import images via Magmi by using images from other server

Tags: image, import, server, magento-1.9, magmi

I need to import images from other server using magmi, actually my products in server 1, but my all images present at server 2 how can i import server 2 images for my server 1 products, how can i do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server its still online you can import the product images using a URL.  So instead of /media/import/filename.jpg you might use something like http://www.server1.com/media/filename.jpg. Magmi will literally download the file from the web and store it to server 2.

Comment: Hi brain,, how can I import products images for my multi store, single store images importing working good, after added store I can't able to import products images...   How can i solve this issue... my CSV like https://snag.gy/e3kioC.jpg